# List files that only have number in names

Tags: bash, shell, file, numbers, find

I have a directory with these files:

```
1.html 22.html 333.html zxc.html
```

I want to get a list of the html files that only have digits in their name:

```
1.html 22.html 333.html
```

I thought this would work

```
find . -regex '^[0-9]+\.html'
```

or

```
ls -al | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.html$'
```

But I get nothing. My idea is to get the html files with only digits in their names and pass them to sed to do a substitution.I'm using linux and bash

Comment: `find`'s `-regex` matches against the whole path, not just the filename, so try `find . -regex '.*/[0-9]+\.html'`.

Comment: @Biffen the shouldn't this work `ls | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.html$'` ? but your find solution works

Comment: Depends on what `ls` prints, which is why you [shouldn't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). `command ls | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.html$'` happens to work for me, but I still wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: `ls -l | grep -e '[0-9]\+\.html'` it works !

Comment: I've found that `ls  | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.html$'` also works but not the first time I tried it, I thing it was because of my remote shell

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`find`'s `-regex` matches against the whole path, not just the filename (I myself seem to forget this once for every time I use it).

Thus, you can use:

```
find . -regex '.*/[0-9]+\.html'
```

(`^` and `$` aren't necessary since it always tests against the whole path.)

Using `find` also has advantages when you want to do something with the files, e.g. using the built-in `-exec`, `-print0` and pipe to `xargs -0` or even (using Bash):

```
while IFS='' read -r -d '' file
do
  # ...
done < <(find . -regex '.*/[0-9]+\.html' -print0)
```

`echo` with a glob, `ls|grep`, etc. tend to stop working when filenames contain spaces (or even newlines) (which I realise won't happen in this case; it's more of a matter of future-proofing and making good habits).

Answer (score 5):

Use an extended glob:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo +([0-9]).html
1.html 22.html 333.html
```

With `extglob` enabled, `+(pattern)` matches one or more of `pattern`. Note that I am just using `echo` to show which files match - how you use the glob depends on what you want to do with it.

To print each file on a separate line, you can use:

```
printf '%s\n' +([0-9]).html
```

Each file matching the pattern is passed as a separate argument to `printf` so you don't have to worry about things like spaces or other interesting characters in filenames.

To iterate over these files, it's as simple as:

```
for file in +([0-9]).html; do 
    echo "$file"
done
```

Again, the shell takes care of any potential problems with interesting filenames, so you don't have to worry about it.